# url() and title() method in Cypress are returning empty stirng

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm tring get to url after opening a new page and validate it. And also trying to validate title as well. But cy.url() and cy.title() every time returing empty string, and throwing a error. Help me if you can.

```
  it.only("Testing new tab opening", ()=>{
    cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/")
    cy.xpath("//a[@id='opentab']").invoke("removeAttr", "target").click();
    cy.title().should("eq", "QAClick Academy - A Testing Academy to Learn, Earn and Shine");
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It works ok for me, but maybe there is a network lag on your system

- increase timeout

  ```js
  cy.title({timeout:20_000}).should(..)
  ```
- add another assertion before the `cy.title()`

  ```js
  cy.contains('h1', 'Practice Page').should('not.exist')
  ```

Also recommended but not required

- remove xpath, use

  ```js
  cy.get('a#opentab').invoke(...
  ```
- start from the page you want to test

  ```js
  cy.visit('https://www.qaclickacademy.com')
  ```

Comment: If I start from that particular page then all is ok. 
But the problem starts when I'm going to another page from main website and trying to  return it's url or title.
Otherwise it's all ok.